# Get Date difference between a date and datetime fields using "Floor"

Tags: sql, datetime, oracle10g, floor

I am trying to get number of day differences using `Floor` function between a date and a datetime field. But i am getting one extra day.
This is how I`m doing->

```
SELECT col,col1,FLOOR(col-col1) FROM tab_name
```

Here col is just Date field,Col1 is DateTime Field

Any idea?

Comment: Arion,I was wrong, I thought i`l get date difference with that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no Date without time in oracle.
A date always contains the time as well (even if you don't show it).

I don't see why you're using `floor`, I think you want `trunc` ie:

```
SELECT col,col1, col- trunc(col1) FROM tab_name
```

Comment: Cade,Thanks for the answer it works fine,I was wrong with the floor concept.